# local package repository on custom server can't be authenticated

Tags: server, apt, package-management, updates, repository

I successfully setup a local package repository on custom server with the following steps

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
cd /var/www/html
mkdir debian
cp /path/to/mydeb.deb /var/www/html/debian
dpkg-scanpackages debian /dev/null | gzip -9c > debian/Packages.gz
```

while on the client

```
vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

add `deb http://54.68.121.138 debian/`to the end of the file

```
sudo apt-get update
```

There shows the below warning message

> W: The repository 'http://54.68.121.138 debian/ Release' does not have a
>   Release file. N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated
>   and is therefore potentially dangerous to use. N: See apt-secure(8)
>   manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

If I install it by `sudo apt-get install mydeb`, I will get prompted with

> Install these packages without verification? [y/N]

If I enter `y` I can still successfully install mydeb on the client, but what should I do on the server to make the client thinks the repository is authenticated and verified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone is interested. The solution to this problem is put `deb [arch=amd64 trusted=yes] http://54.68.121.138 debian/` in the end of `/etc/apt/sources.list` instead of just `deb http://54.68.121.138 debian/`